# Generate report from Django based on user input

Tags: django, reportlab

I'm trying to generate a report from Django based on radio buttons in a template, but having trouble getting data back from the template to determine which variant of the report should be generated.

Template snippet:

```
<form action="{% url projects.views.projectreport reporttype %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
    <input type="radio" name="reporttype"  value="All">All<br>
    <input type="radio" name="reporttype"  value="Current">Current</p>
    <input type = "submit" value="Print Project Report">
    </form>
```

View snippet:

```
 reporttype = 'all'
    if 'current' in request.POST:
        reporttype = 'current'
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'project_list': project_list, 'reporttype': reporttype}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can return a value from the template to the same view, but this goes to a different view (projects.views.projectreport). I'm probably doing something really basic wrong...

J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be "current" that is in `request.POST`, it would be reporttype. `request.POST` is a dictionary-like object, so checking in will check keys, not values. The value of reporttype could be 'Current' or 'All'. So just change your code so

```
reporttype = request.POST['reporttype']
```

This will set `reporttype` to be either All or Current (assuming you have a default set in the html - which currently you do not).  You could also do what you were attempting by doing

```
reporttype = request.POST.get('reporttype', 'All').lower()
```

which will set the value to either the value passed in from the radio button, or to the default 'All'.  It also appears you want it lower cased, so sticking `lower()` on the end should handle that for you.

Comment: Messed about with that a bit and I think I've solved it. It seems to be a GET rather than a POST as it's redirected to another page. I'm still learning the difference. Thanks for the help.